# Accessing Requirejs Global variable

Tags: requirejs

globals.js file:

```
define(function(require) {
    "use strict";
    return {
        "libsPath": "../../"
    };
});
```

index.html file:

```
<script>
 var require = {
        deps: ["js/globals"],
        callback: function(Globals) {
            libsPath = Globals.libsPath;
            console.log(libsPath);
        }
    };
</script>
<script data-main="main.js" src="libs/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

main.js file:

```
require.config({
        baseUrl: './js/',
        paths: {
           'jquery': '../../libs/jquery'
        }
});
```

I want to use libsPath as global variable in my require.config option as below: something like require.libsPath

```
require.config({
        baseUrl: './js/',
        paths: {
           'jquery': require.libsPath + 'libs/jquery'
        }
});
```

Is there any way to achieve this? In Short; How can i use the require global variable in my main.js configuration ?

Comment: I don't understand the `<script>` tag and `require` global var.  Couldn't you just put `require(['js/globals'], function(globals) {})` around your `require.config` call?

Comment: Yes! Yes! could have done that...anyways..Thanks...https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/1072